# Inserting large amounts of data in Django via the shell

Tags: python, django, slug

I currently have a Django environment set up with postgres. Im trying to run a simple script in the shell that is taking way too long to complete.

Is there an efficient way of updating all records in a postgres table in Django?

My table is called City and it contains about 200,000 cities.

This is the script I'm running in python manage.py shell :

```
from locations.models import City
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
counter = 0
for obj in City.objects.all():
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter % 1000 == 0:
        print counter
    obj.city_name_slug = slugify(obj.city_name) + "-" + slugify(obj.region)
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transaction, it will speed up your queries.  Also replace the `obj.save()` call with the `filter().update()` combination, this is the fastest way to change the single field in DB:

```
from locations.models import City
from django.db import transaction
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
counter = 0
with transaction.atomic():
    for obj in City.objects.all():
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter % 1000 == 0:
            print counter
        slug = slugify(obj.city_name) + "-" + slugify(obj.region)
        City.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update(city_name_slug=slug)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It seems that my ec2 instance is stuck. I will report back on this solution once I figure out how to stop the processes that are bugging my instance out.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try out your solution. Worked great- whole thing finished in less than three minutes. Thanks!